# Select Data based on Table's Order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables in my db(sql server).  1st table is my main table, i'm trying to update/insert new records into my main table from the rest two tables

based on 3 criterias.

1. I want to maintain all the records from tbl1 which is my main table.
2. If we come across duplicate records that is same id1, id2,id3, id4 in more than 2 tables ie tbl2_2020 and tbl3_2019, then i want to take the record from the most recent one(recent one is selected based on year which is in the tbl name) & there should no duplicate records in the final table.
3. Unique records which are not there in tbl1 but in tbl2 or tbl3 should be picked
4. Have a separate column in the final tbl that describes the source of the record

```
---my attempt so far (didnt work though :-) )
select COALESCE(t1.id1, t2.id1, t3.id1) as id1,
       COALESCE(t1.id2, t2.id2, t3.id2) as id2,
       .....so on for all the fields
       from tbl1_2021 t1 full join tbl2_2020 t2 ON
       t1.id1= t2.id and t1.id2=t2.id2 and t1.id3=t2.id3 and t1.id4=t2.id4
       full join
      tbl3_2019 t3 ON
          t2.id1= t3.id1 and t2.id2=t3.id2 and t2.id3=t3.id3 and t2.id4=t3.id4
```

tb1_2021: ( main tbl )

```
| id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | name | age | website | nation | email | address |
| 1   | 11  | 111 | 1111| raj  | 20  | .com    | india  |       | india addr |
| 2   | 22  | 222 | 2222| roger| 21  | .usa    | usa    |x@x.com| usa |
```

tbl2_2020:

```
| id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | website | name | age | nation | email | zipcode | parentname | device |
| 1   | 11  | 111 | 1111| .com    | raj  | 20 | india   |       |         |            |        |
| 3   | 33  | 333 | 3333| .ca     | amy  | 24 | uk      | amy   |  zip333 |  sage      | ipad   |
```

tbl3_2019:

```
| id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | name | age | website | nation | email | address |
| 3   | 33  | 333 | 3333|      |     |         |        |       |         |
| 2   | 22  | 222 | 2222| roger| 21  | .usa    | usa    |x@x.com|        |
| 4   | 44  | 444 | 4444| nick| 28   |  .irl   | uk     |n@n.com| nickadr|
```

Final table ( the output )

```
| id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | name | age | website | nation | email | address | source
| 1   | 11  | 111 | 1111| raj  | 20  | .com    | india  |       |india addr| tbl_2021
| 2   | 22  | 222 | 2222| roger| 21  | .usa    | usa    |x@x.com| usa      | tbl_2021
| 3   | 33  | 333 | 3333| amy  | 24  | .ca     | uk     |       |          | tbl_2020
| 4   | 44  | 444 | 4444| nick | 28  | .irl    | uk     |n@n.com| nickaddr | tbl_2019
```

Comment: If you want records from the main table, where do rows 3 and 4 come from?

Comment: If you have different tables for each year, you have a design flaw. Hopefully the reason for your question is to fix this? If not, it should be.

Comment: Seems like, however, what you are after is a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Alternatively you could use a `UNION ALL` with `NOT EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff , the 3rd and 4th recs come from the 3rd criteria that i've mentioned in the question. Unique recs which are not present in tbl1 but in tbl2 or 3 are eligible to be picked.

Comment: Hello @Larnu, Thanks for the feedback! I don't deny that, unfortunately i've to dwell through these different data blocks till there's a system in place.

Comment: @Larnu i tried **COALESCE** mixed with **FULL OUTER JOIN**, but there was mismtach prolly due to my bad understanding of the query. I was hesitant to drop that query in the desc as it would be no were match to the soln. :)

Comment: If you've made an attempt, you should include it in your question, @lavanya_satheesh .

Comment: @Larnu I've made an edit and added what i did. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query

```
SELECT id1
      ,id2
      ,id3
      ,id4
      ,name
      ,age
      ,website
      ,nation
      ,email
      ,address
      ,source
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id1, id2, id3, id4 ORDER BY a.year DESC) [rowId]
FROM (
    SELECT id1, id2, id3, id4, name, age, website, nation, email, address, 'tbl_2021' source, 2021 [year]
    FROM tbl1_2021
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT id1, id2, id3, id4, name, age, website, nation, email, address, 'tbl_2020' source, 2020 [year]
    FROM tbl2_2020
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT id1, id2, id3, id4, name, age, website, nation, email, address, 'tbl_2019' source, 2019 [year]
    FROM tbl3_2019
    ) a
) b
WHERE b.rowId = 1
    ORDER BY b.id1
```

Comment: Thank you @Sowmyadhar! I will certainly try this query and post the query feedback here. I appreciate your kindness and effort!! :)